# Pointer arithmetic Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, pointer-arithmetic

Consider the following two useless C++ functions.

Compiled with GCC (4.9.2, 32- or 64-bit) both functions returning the same value as expected.

Compiled with Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2017 (unmanaged code) both functions returning different values.

What I've tried:

- brackets, brackets, brackets
- explicit casts to char
- sizeof(char) is evaluated to 1
- debug / release version
- 32- / 64-bit

What's going on here? <strike>It seems to be a fundamental bug in VS.</strike>

```
char test1()
{
    char buf[] = "The quick brown fox...", *pbuf = buf;

    char value = (*(pbuf++) & 0x0F) | (*(pbuf++) & 0xF0);

    return value;
}


char test2()
{
    char buf[] = "The quick brown fox...", *pbuf = buf;

    char a = *(pbuf++) & 0x0F;
    char b = *(pbuf++) & 0xF0;
    char value =  a | b;

    return value;
}
```

**Edit:**

- It's not an attempt to blame VS (as mentioned in the posts).
- It's not a matter of signed or unsigned.
- It's not a matter of the order of evaluation left and right side of the or-operator. Changing the order of the assignments of a and b in test2() yields to a third result.
- But the simultaneity is a good point. It seems the ordering of evaluation is defined to be undefined. In a first step, the generated code evaluates the complete expression in test1() without incrementing any pointer. In a second step the pointers will be incremented. Since the incrementation has no effect and the data remains unchanged after this specific operation, the optimizer will remove the code.

Sorry for inconveniences, but this is not what i would expect. In no language.

For completeness, here the disassembled code of test1():

```
0028102A  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
0028102D  movsx       edx,byte ptr [ecx]  
00281030  and         edx,0Fh  
00281033  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
00281036  movsx       ecx,byte ptr [eax]  
00281039  and         ecx,0F0h  
0028103F  or          edx,ecx  

00281041  mov         byte ptr [ebp-1],dl  
00281044  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
00281047  add         edx,1  
0028104A  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],edx  
0028104D  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
00281050  add         eax,1  

00281053  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax
```

Comment: | operator doesn't guarantee evaluation order.

Comment: *It seems to be a fundamental bug in VS* -- Make sure you do research before blaming the engineers.

Comment: There is no sequence point between operands of a | expression so the behavior is undefined in the first example. I guess there is a fundamental bug in your understandings of the language.

Comment: Reopened. Where are we heading here? A "canonical" page for all C++ questions. Come on, the duplicate close is for "exact duplicates". Closing this to "undefined behaviour and sequence points" is hardly appropriate. The SE database can hold more than 1Mb of text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour of `(*(pbuf++) & 0x0F) | (*(pbuf++) & 0xF0);` is *undefined*. `|` (unlike `||`) is **not** a sequencing point, and so you have simultaneous reads and writes on `pbuf` in the same program step.

Not a VS bug therefore. (Such things rarely are: a golden rule is not to blame the compiler.)

(Note also that `char` can be either `signed` or `unsigned`. That can introduce differences in code like yours.)

Comment: I'm sure you could have found a duplicate about expression UB, easily.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I could have linked the standard too (a dupe target for any C++ question), but that would not have allowed me to talk about the VS bug part.

Comment: The VS bug part has already been addressed in comments, where it belongs.